# Count the Rows in Sigma Grid

Tags: javascript, sigma-grid-control

I am new here using the Sigma Grid. How can I count the rows in Sigma Grid? I just want the number of rows that are appear in my screen.

thanks for advance.

Comment: I think you should provide an example on it .. and explain what you want from that..

Comment: I will add a data on the grid then it will go count the rows. That is the exact  scenario what I gonna do.

Comment: It is so hard to search some problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

All data present in sigma grid:

```
var allSelectedRecords = myGrid.dataset.data;
```

This will give the number of rows present in sigma grid:

```
allSelectedRecords.length;
```